# Basic Decision Tree with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

This is what I have so far. It is not lining up properly when I run the code.

[image]

```
    \begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={.9\textwidth}{.6\textheight},center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge/.append style = {-Straight Barb, thick,
                            shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm},
                        ]
\matrix (tree) [matrix of nodes,
                nodes={circle, draw, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0mm},
                column sep=2cm, row sep=1cm
                ]
{

                 & $C_{i+1,j+1}$    \\
$C_{i,j}$       &$C_{i+1,j}$  \\
                 & $C_{i+1,j}$  \\
    };
\draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-1-3) node{};
\draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-3-3) node{};
\draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-5-3) node{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{adjustbox} 
 \end{frame}
```

Comment: \documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{default}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} 

\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{subtitle}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{footlinecolor}{fg=white,bg=green}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
 \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-10pt} \textit{Where Wall Street Goes to School} \hfill \insertpagenumber}
}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

Comment: The code is still not formatted properly

Comment: which code? yours? mine? you not response on got answer. from mine answer to the tree is showed in your question is straightforward ... i can adopt my answer to this tree, but first you sould  me inform, if answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399404/decision-tree-in-latex-with-tikz/399406#399406 fulfill your expectation and if not, what is you not liked in it.

Comment: \begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={.9\textwidth}{.6\textheight},center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge/.append style = {-Straight Barb, thick,
                            shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm},
                        ]
\matrix (tree) [matrix of nodes,
                nodes={circle, draw, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0mm},
                column sep=2cm, row sep=1cm
                ]
{
|[label=left:{$C_{i,j+1}$}]|   \\
|[label=left:{$C_{i,j}$}]|    &   |[label=right:{$C_{i+1,j}$}]|     \\
|[label=left:{$C_{i,j-1}$}]| \\  
};

Comment: \draw[->] (tree-1-1) -- (tree-2-2) node {};
\draw[->] (tree-2-1) -- (tree-2-2) node {};
\draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-2-2) node {};
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{adjustbox} 
 
\end{frame}

Comment: This is the code that work for the first question but it don't know how to make it work for the second question

Comment: don't write code in comments! please, edit your question and add code there. if you have problems with this, make yourself familiar how to ask question here, how to respond on received answers etc.